# How to link to a menu item from a module

Tags: joomla, menu, hyperlink, module

I have a module that is supposed to display the titles of articles from a category and link to them in a menu.  The articles have been linked via a menu to create sef urls.  When I try to link to the article from the module the URL is not the SEF friendly version.  How do I link to the menu item from within the module?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a module you have written, you can parse non SEF URLs to their SEF version using JRoute

For example,

```
echo JRoute::_('index.php?view=article&id=1&catid=20');
```

Comment: When I do this its appending ?id=xxx to the end of the url.  And those id's are wrong.

Comment: If you have set up menu items, you should just need 'index.php?Itemid=XXX', replacing XXX with your menu item id.  If you are sending other parameters, then how JRoute works will depend on how the component you are linking to has set up its router.

Comment: If that does not work, can you give an example of your JRoute code, and the URL it is outputting.